# Transient solution system of differential equations obtained from master equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, quantum-optics, differential-equations, open-quantum-systems

I have to solve the following equation (or at least obtain an approximate estimate) for the diagonal terms of the density matrix. We consider that the initial state is a coherent state $\rho_{n,n}(0)=e^{-|\alpha|^2}|\alpha|^{2n}/n!$ .I don't mind whether you can help me to obtain an exact/approximate solution derived by hand or using a symbolic program (Mathematica is the one I know better).

A master equation for the reduced density operator leads to the next equation for the diagonal elements of the matrix. This equation was deduced from the master equation evaluating the terms $\langle n | . |n\rangle$ between Fock states $|n\rangle$. 
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d \rho_{n n}}{d t}=\kappa_{n} \rho_{n+2, n+2}+\mu_{n} \rho_{n+1, n+1}-\eta_{n} \rho_{n, n}
\end{equation}
with $\kappa_{n}=(n+2)(n+1) \gamma_{2}$, $\mu_{n}=(n+1)\left(\Gamma+n^{2} \gamma_{3}\right)$, $\eta_{n}=n\left[\Gamma+(n-1) \gamma_{2}+(n-1)^{2} \gamma_{3}\right]$.
It is sometimes named as a Pauli Master Equation.
It seems this equation belong to the class of "classical master equation for a one step process", or maybe in this case a two step process, I'm not sure.

From now on, I will write the subindex $\{n,n\}$ as $n$. The system can be written in matrix-like form:

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \dot{\rho _0} \\
 \dot{\rho _1} \\
 \dot{\rho _2} \\
 \square  \\
 \square  \\
 \dot{\rho _n} \\
 \square  \\
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & \Gamma  & 2 \text{$\gamma $2} & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  \\
 \square  & -\Gamma  & 2 (\Gamma +\text{$\gamma $3}) & 6 \text{$\gamma $2} & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  \\
 \square  & \square  & -2 (\Gamma +\text{$\gamma $2}+\text{$\gamma $3}) & 3 (\Gamma +4 \text{$\gamma $3}) & 12 \text{$\gamma $2} & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  \\
 \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  \\
 \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  \\
 \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & -\eta_n & \mu_n & \kappa_n& \square  \\
 \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  & \square  \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \rho _0 \\
 \rho _1 \\
 \rho _2 \\
 \square  \\
 \square  \\
 \rho _n \\
 \square  \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
Which is a tridiagonal matrix with coefficients in the main diagonal and the two superior diagonals. I don't know if this differential system of equations has been studied.
I a paper it is stated that it is possible to write solutions for $\rho_{0}$ and $\rho_{1}$ in the integral form,
for the initial coherent state to obtain the quotient: $\rho_{00}(t)/\rho_{11}(t)$ and that the rest of elements can be estimated from the expansion series of the evolution operator of the first displayed equation, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

I am looking for $\rho_{nn}$ as a function of time. Thanks,

**edit**: I added the equal. It is a system of infinite equations, I am not sure if you can call the matrix a square o non-square matrix. The system satisfy the recurrence relation that is specify in the first equation and I am lookin to obtain $\rho_{nn}$ as a function of time. Thanks. I will edit further if required

**edit**:The system satisfy the recurrence relation that is specified in the first equation and I am looking to obtain $ρ_{nn}$ as a function of time. For example if the initial estate was $\rho_{0,0}=1$ and $\rho_{n,n}=0$ then I could easily solve this $dρ_0/dt=− \eta_0 \rho_0$ and then $ρ_0=exp(−\eta_0 t)$ and that's it. The other elements remain zero. But this is other case, all the levels are initially populated. Well, I have now realized that $\eta_0=0$ so the vacuum state would not evolve, which is hardly surprising.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear, thanks

Comment: Your "system" isn't an equation (there is no equals sign) and as it stands the matrix doesn't seem to be square - it looks more like $(n+2)\times n$. But when you fix those problems, and if the $\gamma_i$ are constants, this looks like a standard first order linear differential equation to me.

Comment: I guess I'm still not clear on what you are asking -- you need to solve a (maybe?) non-square system of equations. Which part of solving it are you stuck on? How to march in time, or maybe how to solve the matrix system, or maybe something else? It seems like a fairly typical linear ODE problem as written, but I am not familiar with the nuances of the equation so maybe there's something more here that isn't obvious...

Comment: I added the equal. It is a system of infinite equations, I am not sure if you can call the matrix a square o non-square matrix. The system satisfy the recurrence relation that is specify in the first equation and I am lookin to obtain $\rho_{nn}$ as a function of time. Thanks. I will edit further if required

Comment: The system satisfy the recurrence relation that is specify in the first equation and I am looking to obtain $\rho_{nn}$ as a function of time. For example if the initial estate was $\rho_{0,0}=1$ and $\rho_{n,n}=0$ then I could easily solve this $d \rho_{0}/ dt=-\Gamma_0 \rho_0$ and then $\rho_{0}=\exp(-\Gamma_0 t)$ and that's it. The other elements remain zero. But this is other case, all the levels are initially populated

Comment: OKay -- I'll have to let somebody else who knows the specifics to answer then. I suspect you'll have to truncate it somewhere to make it solvable... usually infinite equations aren't tractable. There is probably some $n$ large enough that the terms are small and can be neglected, introducing an error of course but hopefully an acceptable one. If the summation over $n$ is not convergent, then I suspect there's no way to solve it but I'd have to defer to somebody else for that.

Comment: Please don't litter your posts with "edit" labels. All SE posts are version controlled, so just seemlessly integrate the new material into your post; interested users can see what changed by checking out the edit history (find by clicking the "edited <time>" at the bottom of the post).

Comment: I will have that into account for the future

Comment: It would be nice to have a method like the one described in this paper https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/26441/2/PhysRevE.91.062119.pdf, but they have a proper tridiagonal system $\dot{P}_{n}(t)=a_{n} P_{n-1}(t)+b_{n} P_{n+1}(t)+\left(-a_{n+1}-b_{n-1}\right) P_{n}(t)$, while mine involves the main diagonal $P_{n}$ and the two superior diagonals $P_{n+1}$ and $P_{n+2}$. the first equation in my post could be recast $\dot{P}_n=\kappa_{n} P_{n+2}+\mu_{n} P_{n+1}-\eta_{n} P_{n}$